# Apache2 wildcard subdomains

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I've a question to see if it's possible as my search results are turning up empty or with the same blog telling something totally different...

Basically I've added an A Record for *.mydomain.com to my IP... ok, simple stuff over.

Now I've created a VirtualHost which looks something alike:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/mydomain.com/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the above is fine for if I want them all pointing to the index.php page.  However I'm wanting a little more complex VirtualHost...

The link will look someting alike this:

http://someusername.mydomain.com/public/repositoryname

This would then point to something alike the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com

    <Location /home/svn/{someusername}/{public}/{repositoryname}>
        #Some more code in here...
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously the Location variables for:

```
{someusername} - Will be what the subdomain is
{public} - Will be the first GET parameter from the url query string
{repositoryname} - Will be the second GET paramter from the url query string
```

Now I know this is possibly bending Apache WildCards to the limit, but I need to know if this is achievable or not.

Many thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to achieve this by enabling mod_perl and writing a custom perl script.  Anyone with a similar issue definately look into using Perl for this!